# Getting content from object with symbol in name

Tags: php, object

I'm getting this object with JSON and getting name by using

```
$programItem[0]->Name
```

but if I try to use

```
$programitem[0]->@id
```

This does not work I think because of the @ but I can't remove this, anyway I can get this working?

```
[0] => stdClass Object
(
    [@id] => 123
    [name] => Companyname
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place the key inside {''}

```
$programItem->{'@id'}
```

Comment: While correct, you really need to give an example like the other answer

Answer (score 2):

You can get it like

```
echo $obj->{'@stuff'};
```

See a working example:

[Php code online](https://3v4l.org/ciDEP)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a variable variable to get to it

```
$var = '@id';
echo $a->$var;
```

[Example](https://3v4l.org/2ZkhT)